# Does Stack Exchange play Call of Duty?

Tags: discussion, error-message

I was looking at the [error page](https://stackoverflow.com/error) and noticed this:

[image: Confused dev w/ Call of Duty]

- Where were these photos taken (it doesn't look like your office)?
- What sort of device is that they're [banging their heads on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXxOo.jpg)?
- And who are those confused devs?

**And do the Stack Exchange devs play Call of Duty?**

Comment: [What kind of computer is being used in “Workin on ur problemz”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37597/what-kind-of-computer-is-being-used-in-workin-on-ur-problemz) and [How can I see all the images of the error page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203590/how-can-i-see-all-the-images-of-the-error-page)

Answer (score 3):

At least some members of the Stack <del>Exchange</del> Overflow dev team are (former) fans of WoW, [such as Nick Craver](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/welcome-valued-associate-nick-craver/).

Former co-founder Jeff Atwood seems to be more of an FPS kind of guy,

> every Call of Duty multiplayer youtube video
>   ever http://t.co/NJ2t5CKHQQ
>
> —
>   Jeff Atwood (@codinghorror) [June 1, 2013](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/340677813369704448)
>
> I wonder if soldiers find Call of Duty as much
>   of an affront to their profession as some musicians apparently do for
>   Rock Band
>
> — Jeff Atwood (@codinghorror) [July 29,
>   2008](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/871486678)
>
> Call of Duty: Black Ops - great production
>   values, was kind of meh overall until I got to the Kennedy anti-zombie
>   white house endgame!!
>
> — Jeff Atwood (@codinghorror) [November
>   11, 2010](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/2662419860029440)
>
> @tenderlove BUT YOUR
>   DUTY
>
> — Jeff Atwood (@codinghorror) [June
>   16, 2015](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/610631070401232898)

You can even find Jeff occasionally giving pro FPS tips on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/, such as [Is there a beginner's guide to Battlefield 3 multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33345/is-there-a-beginners-guide-to-battlefield-3-multiplayer/33427#33427).

CEO and co-founder Joel Spolsky once asked a question about Angry Birds—[How can I beat level 3-15 in Angry Birds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/how-can-i-beat-level-3-15-in-angry-birds)—but I always assumed that he eventually gave up in deep frustration and moved on to beating Stack <del>Exchange</del> Overflow competitors instead.

Comment: Ahah, so it's probably Atwood's doing :-)